# Padding between Textview border and drawableLeft

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my `TextView` layout:

[image: my textview]

As you can see, there is a padding between the border (the `stroke`) and the image inside the `TextView`, which is given using `drawableLeft` attribute.
I know I could use `drawablePadding` attribute to adjust the padding between the image and the text, but I want to remove the padding between the **stroke and the image**. Can I do something like that? And, possibily, from XML?

This is the `TextView`'s layout:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPlate2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_italian_plate"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/plate_textview"/>
```

and this is `plate_textview` drawable, where I simply add a `stroke`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use drawablepadding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your are using image from `mipmap` folder. `mipmap` is only used for `launcher` icons and its added extra `padding` and `elevation` when show on `view`.

> Always keep `resource` icons in `drawable` folder and use it as
>   `@drawable/ic_italian_plate`.

**#.** You can add `padding` and `corners` to custom `drawable` using `<padding>` and `<corners>`.

**Update `plate_textview.xml` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/black"/>

    <padding
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="8dp" />

    <corners
        android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

**Update `TextView` as below:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPlate2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_italian_plate"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:text="I-123-4568"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@drawable/plate_textview"/>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~